# Array doesn't stores into the mongodb database

Tags: reactjs, arrays, database, mongodb

I'm working the react project and I'm trying to fetch the data from the sighup page of my website and in which it contain the multiple check buttons that I stored in useState variables but when I submit the form, all the data is stored in the database but the Interest section array will be empty.[here's I've got this things done but the array isn't.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NytX.png)

I try to change the code according to my knowledge, like the values are stored in console but it is not going to store in the database, but still I got another error like after submitting the form, whole page shows me errors.

Here's the code that I made.

```
//SignUp.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style/Form.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function MyForm() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setpassword] = useState('');
    const [acceptedTerms, setAcceptedTerms] = useState(false);
    const [Interests, setInterests] = useState([]);
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!name || !email || !password || !acceptedTerms) {
            alert('Please fill out all required fields and accept terms.');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Name:', name);
        console.log('Email:', email);
        console.log('Accepted Terms:', acceptedTerms);
        console.log('Selected Option:', Interests);
        console.log('Password: ', password)
        alert("Name: " + name + " Password:" + password);

        try {
            const userData = { name, email, password, Interests };
            await axios.post('/api/register', userData);
            alert("User registered successfully");
            // Clear form fields after successful registration
            setName('');
            setEmail('');
            setpassword('');
            setAcceptedTerms(false);
            setInterests([]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error registering user:', error);
            alert("Error registering user");
        }
    };
    const handleButtonClick = (buttonValue) => {
        const updatedInterests = [...Interests];
        const index = updatedInterests.indexOf(buttonValue);
        if (index === -1) {
            updatedInterests.push(buttonValue);
        } else {
            updatedInterests.splice(index, 1);
        }
        setInterests(updatedInterests);
    };
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='App'>
            <label>
                Name:
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} autoFocus required
                /><br />
            </label>
            <label>
                Email:
                <input
                    type="email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} required
                /><br />
            </label>
            <label>
                Password:
                <input
                    type="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setpassword(e.target.value)} required
                /><br />
            </label>
            <label>
                <input className='check'
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={acceptedTerms}
                    onChange={(e) => setAcceptedTerms(e.target.checked)} required
                />
                I accept the terms and conditions
            </label><br />
            <p>Selete the topics from below that you want to read the most:-</p>
            <div className='checkOptions'>
                <p className="d-inline-wrap gap-1">
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('All') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('All')}
                    >
                        All
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('Business') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Business')}
                    >
                        Business
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('Science') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Science')}
                    >
                        Science
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('Technology') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Technology')}
                    >
                        Technology
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('Health') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Health')}
                    >
                        Health
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className={`btn m-1 ${Interests.includes('Sports') ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick('Sports')}
                    >
                        Sports
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <link /><br /><br />
            <p>seems you have visited before?  <a href="Form">Sign in</a> now!</p>
        </form>
    );
}
```

```
//server.js

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors'); // Import cors package

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// MongoDB connection
mongoose.connect('[mongodbs_database_connection_link]', {
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'));

// Use CORS middleware
app.use(cors());

// Define user schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    Interests: [String]
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// API endpoint for user registration
app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, password, Interests } = req.body;
        const newUser = new User({ name, email, password, Interests });
        await newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error registering user' });
    }
});

// Start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Did you check with the network inspector, that the POST body in fact contains the correct values for the `Interests` property? Did you check at the backend if the `req.boy` in fact contains the correct values for the `Interests` property?

Comment: "*but still I got another error like after submitting the form,*" mind to share *what* errors your get?

Comment: Thank you for reaching me out. I don't know how, but the error is now solved. i didn't change the code the same code I ran again and it's working properly.
And the error that  I've told, is about the make fields empty after submitting the form.
like it wasn't working and after submit the form and successfully register, the complete page shows me error(don't know what's the error).